# In unity custom shader materials appear pink

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, urp

I'm using Unity 2020.3.20f1.
I created a 3D object (sphere) and applied a material which has a custom shader.
Now the whole sphere appears pink.

I'm using URP, but I added it to an existing project. What I already tried is to upgrade the material to URP material, but it didn't fix it.

Thanks!

Comment: Pink generally means the material (or corresponding shader) isn't designed for URP.  You might just need to right-click upgrade it.

Comment: I did try it, didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't add URP as the fefault shader in the graphic settings. (I had to manually create a URP renderer asset tho)
After adding it and upgradeing ALL materials to URP it started working.

Comment: Glad you got it going.